# How to identify who edited yaml or property file in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, edit, kubectl

If someone has edit yaml or property file of any running service, then how should I know who and when edit command was used on that particular service.

kubectl edit deploy ServiceName -n NameSpace

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes audit logs should tell you that.Kubernetes auditing provides a security-relevant chronological set of records documenting the sequence of activities that have affected system by individual users, administrators or other components of the system.

The known audit levels are:

1. None - don’t log events that match this rule.
2. Metadata - log request metadata (requesting user, timestamp, resource, verb, etc.) but not request or response body.
3. Request - log event metadata and request body but not response body. This does not apply for non-resource requests.
4. RequestResponse - log event metadata, request and response bodies. This does not apply for non-resource requests.

You could write a audit policy like below

```
apiVersion: audit.k8s.io/v1 # This is required.
kind: Policy
# Don't generate audit events for all requests in RequestReceived stage.
omitStages:
  - "RequestReceived"
rules:
  # Log deployment changes at RequestResponse level
  - level: RequestResponse
    resources:
    - group: "apps/v1"
      resources: ["deployments"]
```

You need to apply this via `--audit-policy-file` flag of kube API Server.

Also you can Fluentd to collect the audit logs as in this [guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/audit/#use-fluentd-to-collect-and-distribute-audit-events-from-log-file)

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/audit/

Comment: Thanks for your help !!! Can u help in how and where to apply this .yaml file ? After applying where to get all details about events?